# Receive image (in Android) from multicast server

Tags: android, multicast, android-broadcast, android-networking

I have a PC-server that multicast a image/data. I want to develop a application in android phone to receive that image/data. Could you suggest to me the steps to do it?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you ask for the steps.  I present high level steps with some java pseudo code.

```
MulticastSocket socket; 
MulticastLock mcLock;
WifiLock wifiLock;
DatagramPacket dgram;



// make a socket
socket = new MulticastSocket(...)

// join the multicast group
socket.joinGroup( <your server> )

// obtain wifi lock
wifiLock = ((WifiManager) 
    THIS_CONTEXT.getSystemService(THIS_CONTEXT.WIFI_SERVICE)).createWifiLock("clientWifiLock");
wifiLock.acquire();

// obtain multicast lock
mcLock = ((WifiManager) THIS_CONTEXT.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE))
    .createMulticastLock("replicationMulticastLock");
mcLock.acquire();

// make a datagram packet for receiving
dgram  = new DatagramPacket(...);

// receive data
socket.receive(dgram);
// loop if necessary and receive more data and save it in a buffer
```

You may also need the following permissions in your manifest file
    uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"
    uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" 
    uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" 
    uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
    uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" 
    uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"